# Where can I register a .name domain?

Tags: top-level-domains, domain-registrar

All the popular registrars I know of don't seem to offer this domain, and after Google'ing around for a while I came to an index of registrars for this TLD, but they all seem to be Russian.

Is there a popular (preferably American) domain registrar that offers .name domains?

Answer (score 7):

Verisign maintains [a list of .name registrars here.](http://www.verisigninc.com/en_US/products-and-services/domain-name-services/find-registrar/index.xhtml) You can filter the list either by country or by domain extension (but not both, sadly).

Comment: In light of James' response about the list being out of date, etc. GoDaddy definitely does still offer these, and is the registrar I used for one of my own.

Answer (score 1):

Unofficial List of .name Registrars

http://daniel.gnoutcheff.name/dotname/reglist/

Answer (score 0):

The .name TLD had a brief stay. It was introduced in 2001-2002 and was shortly unsponsered by ICANN. This is why it is hard to find a US Registerer. Verisign does own and manage the TLD but the list posted by Nick is not up to date. The TLD .name was supposed to be for personal use, but never really flourished.

Answer (score 0):

I used 2 Registrars for my .name domains:

- 007names.com (USA)
- hexonet.net (Germany)

The first one much easier to manage and offer additional services, the second one only focused of basics. Both of them provide support for your **@.name** email forwarding which is critical. Many registrars, even Enom.com, who declare support for .name domain registration don't have a clue about .name email forwarding. I am pretty happy with both.